# Update your code without losing what you have? c#

Tags: c#

I have a well functioning code but I have to change a lot of things on it to make it more efficient, my question is, Is there a way to save your code (without creating any new projects) in case I screw things up? Like a time machine on MacOS

Comment: Look up version control (git or svn are the most widely used).

Comment: Source Control? and I don't think this is the right place for this question.

Comment: Try using team foundation service ( http://tfs.visualstudio.com/). It's simple.

Answer (score 0):

You need a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) . It's "like time machine" for code and even better: it provides history, allows you to see differencies between arbitrary versions of your code, go back and forth along the versions and lot more. All the professional developers use Version Control Systems.

Good examples of VCS are Git, SVN, Mercurial. I suggest, that you learn git (mostly adopted now):

- [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book))
- [Fancy gamefied jump-start from GitHub](http://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you're a .NET developer with an MSDN subscription, take a look at [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff637362.aspx). Otherwise, Git or SVN are your go-tos. We run SVN with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) on the client side, and it's been great so far (and free!).